# Videos for higher homotopy groups

Tags: algebraic-topology

Wikipedia states that: Mappings from a 2-sphere to a 2-sphere can be visualized as wrapping a plastic bag around a ball and then sealing it. The sealed bag is topologically equivalent to a 2-sphere, as is the surface of the ball. The bag can be wrapped more than once by twisting it and wrapping it back over the ball.

I am curious how it would look like in reality. Is there any video that illustrates this?